# Performing a shapiro-wilk test on residuals from an LMER and repeated-measures ANOVA

Tags: r, normal-distribution, ggplot2, shapiro-wilk-test

I would like to perform a Shapiro-Wilk test on my data which takes the form of an LMER.

The LMER model is named lmerabsolute.

```
lmerabsolute <- lmer(transform ~ Target*Type + (1|ID), Errortrial)
```

Would I be right in performing a shapiro-wilk test with the following formula:

```
shapiro.test(resid(lmerabsolute))
```

Additionally, I have also performed a repeated-measures ANOVA on another dataset.

```
Oneway <- aov(data=Errortrialraw, Absolutefirststoperror~Trialnumber+Error(ID/Trialnumber))
```

Would I be right in performing a shapiro-wilk test with the following formula:

```
Onewayproject <- proj(Oneway)
residuals <- Onewayproject[[3]]["Residuals"] #here I extract residuals from the 'within stratum'
shapiro.test(residuals)
```

Comment: I would first question why you believe using a hypothesis test for normality with model residuals is a sensible approach. Have you read the answers to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/2492/11849)?

Comment: @Roland yes; I have visually inspected the residuals through a qqplot and they don't seem so convincing but mostly do fall on a straight line: shall I do a Friedman test instead?